# installing older version of python pip

Tags: python

I've got a brand new kubuntu 14.04.01 LTS. It has only python 2.7 supported. I need 2.6 for my work. I've found the [deadsnakes repositories](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) and I've been able to install python2.6. But now I can't find a way to install pip for python 2.6 - how can I do that?

---

Following @AvishBabu's answer, I downloaded the easy setuptools 2.6 egg, so I have easy_install-2.6, but it's installed inside my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages... When I try to install pip for 2.6, I get:

```
$ sudo easy_install-2.6 pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.4
Adding pip 1.5.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

which means, that only pip2.7 is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to install setuptools for Python 2.6 (example :
>   `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg`). Then, you have `easy_install-2.6`.

You can do:

Use the command

```
easy_install-2.6 pip
```

For installing the mysql-python, use like `pip-2.6 install mysql-python`.

See [reference](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5538329/pip-installing-into-an-older-python-version).

Comment: where can I download `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg` from?

Comment: I haven't managed to install pip for 2.6 yet. See my updated question above.